# Formatting for multiple subfunctions in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jQuery filtering plugin [Filtrify](http://luis-almeida.github.com/filtrify/) and having difficulty adding multiple sub-functions.

It works fine until I try and add two callbacks. Here's my best attempt!

```
var ft = $.filtrify("container", "searchbox", {
    close : true,
    callback : { 
        function() {
            destroyPagination();
            setPagination();
        }, 
        function() {
            if ( mismatch.length ) $("div#reset").show();
            else $("div#reset").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

I've hunted around on Stack Overflow, the Filtrify documentation and elsewhere online and I just can't find any info or examples with multiple sub-functions like the above code.

Thanks so much and please feel free to change my question title if I've got the wrong terminology!

Comment: Why do you need two callbacks? Can't you put the code in a single callback? Or create a single callback that calls two other functions?

Comment: How come you don't just merge the code into one callback function?

Comment: Thanks Bart / Justin - excellent points. I actually tried that first and it didn't work but now on second try it magically started working. I must've neglected to include the correct arguments first time round! ** embarrassed

Comment: @Jamie: do you succedd in makind the callbacks working? I don't, on my site http://epos-couch.cloudant.com/epos-couch-test/_design/epos-couch/index.html (the declared callback at line 146 doesn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be based on the design of the plugin.  If the plugin itself does not allow for multiple callbacks (which this one doesn't) then you can't use them.

Instead, just use a single callback.  The callback has three arguments including the match and mismatch list and fires every time a tag is added or removed.